# Recycler VIew and Adapter open Activity with different content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm making news app. I have 2 activities. First activity contains RecyclerView that show's different news item's. For this purpose i created adapter. Here is my adapter code:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<NewsItem> newsItemList;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<NewsItem> newsItemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newsItemList = newsItemList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_row_item, parent, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.newsImage.setImageResource(newsItemList.get(position).getNewsImage());
        holder.newsName.setText(newsItemList.get(position).getNewsName());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",R.string.newsContent1);
                intent.putExtra("image",R.drawable.newsImage1);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsItemList.size();
    }
    public static final class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView newsImage;
        TextView newsName;

        public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            newsImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
            newsName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsName);
        }
    }
}
```

My News.java code look like this

```
public class news extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView newsRecycler;
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        List<NewsItem> newsItems = new ArrayList<>();
        newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1));
        newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1));
        newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1));
        newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1));

        setNewsRecycler(newsItems);*/
    }
        private void setNewsRecycler(List<NewsItem> newsItemsList){
        newsRecycler = findViewById(R.id.newsRecycler);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        newsRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this, newsItemsList);
        newsRecycler.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
    }
}
```

After I created a NewsDetails activity with ImageView and 2 TextView. I gave them IDs. And what I want to do is display different content in this activity based news item selected on NewsActivity. I've already created strings for the TextView and imported images for the ImageView. How can I achieve this? Thanks for the help in advance.

After reviewing liveAnyway's answer i added this to my NewsDetails.java. Image change worked, but text didn't.

```
public class NewsDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_details);

        String newTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        int newImage = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 0);

        TextView newsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newsDetailsContent);
        ImageView newsImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newsDetailsImage);

        newsText.setText(newTitle);
        newsImage.setImageResource(newImage);
    }
}
```

My NewsItem.java file

```
public class NewsItem {

    String newsName;
    Integer newsImage;

    public NewsItem(String newsName, Integer newsImage) {
        this.newsName = newsName;
        this.newsImage = newsImage;
    }

    public String getNewsName() {
        return newsName;
    }

    public void setNewsName(String newsName) {
        this.newsName = newsName;
    }

    public Integer getNewsImage() {
        return newsImage;
    }

    public void setNewsImage(Integer newsImage) {
        this.newsImage = newsImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding text with "text" - this worked. But "R.string.newsArticle1" didn't. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `intent.putExtra()` before `startActivity(intent)` like below

If your NewsItem has few properties

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   //image from newsItemList.get(position).getNewsImage()
   //name from newsItemList.get(position).getNewsName()
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
   //it just example, You can just put any data what you need
   intent.putExtra("name",name);
   intent.putExtra("image",image);
   ...
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

If your NewsItem can be Parcelable

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
   intent.putExtra("newsItem",newsItem);
   
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in your `NewsDetailActivity`

```java
//in onCreate()
String newTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
Int newDrawable = getIntent().getIntExtra("image"); 
//or
NewsItem item = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("newsItem");
```

#### update1

check point

1. `R.string.id` is `int` so you should change like below

```java
int strId = getIntent().getIntExtra("title");
String title = getString(strId);
```

2. you put like this

```java
intent.putExtra("title",R.string.newsContent1);
intent.putExtra("image",R.drawable.newsImage1);
```

It's not good idea

Your `NewsItem` need to have that data(like `R.string.newsContent1`,`R.drawable.newsImage`) and use this from `newsItemList.get(position)`

```java
//for example
int newsContentsStrId =  newsItemList.get(position).getNewsContentsStrId();
int newsImageResId = newsItemList.get(position).getNewsImageResId();
intent.putExtra("title",newsContentsStrId);
intent.putExtra("image",newsImageResId);
```

#### update2

if your `NewsItem` like this

```java
public class NewsItem {
    String newsName;
    Integer newsImage;
    //added more that you need (it just example)
    Integer newsContentsStrId;
    
    public NewsItem(String newsName, Integer newsImage, Integer newsContentsStrId) {
        this.newsName = newsName;
        this.newsImage = newsImage;
        this.newsContentsStrId = newsContentsStrId;
    }

    public String getNewsName() {
        return newsName;
    }

    public void setNewsName(String newsName) {
        this.newsName = newsName;
    }

    public Integer getNewsImage() {
        return newsImage;
    }

    public void setNewsImage(Integer newsImage) {
        this.newsImage = newsImage;
    }

    public Integer getNewsContentsStrId() {
        return newsContentsStrId;
    }

    public void setNewsContentsStrId(Integer newsContentsStrId) {
        this.newsContentsStrId = newsContentsStrId;
    }
}
```

just put this when you construct `NewsItem`, I think you already know.

```java
//in news onCreate()
List<NewsItem> newsItems = new ArrayList<>();
newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1,R.string.newArtical1));
newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1,R.string.newArtical2));
newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1,R.string.newArtical3));
newsItems.add(new NewsItem("Text", R.drawable.im_maincorpus1,R.string.newArtical4));
```

Comment: "your_title" what to do with it? I have newsArticle1 in a string file. Should i put "R.string.newsArticle1"? And don't I need to write the ID of the ImageView or TextView in order for the content being passed to be displayed inside them?

Comment: (first sorry my english bad) Yes you can put your `R.string.id` in `putExtra()` and the View's id in `NewsDetailActivity`  just can be fixed if `NewsDetailActivity` show only selected news. I edited `onClick()`

Comment: I putted your code and nothing happened. Do i have to do anything else?

Comment: Could you update your code? you changed? and show `NewsDetails`?

Comment: check  my update answer. and change the putExtra keys that match your intention for understand better.

Comment: I added my NewsItem code. Can you show me how to add the specified data there?